# Ring Homomorphism over the ring of infinite vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, linear-transformations, abelian-groups

Let $V$ be an infinite dimensional vector space over a division ring $D$ and $R=End(V_D)$. Clearly $R$ is a regular ring.

I am searching to find **a ring homomorphism such as $\sigma:R\rightarrow R$** such that for every idempotent $e\in R$, $\sigma(e)=e$.

I will appreciate if someone gives a hint.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Dear colleague, Thank you very much. It was a typo that I made it true.